# Migrate database from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server that have tables in columns written in Japanese. Because of that I got an error that "columns are empty". If database in English, there are no problems in migrating to MySQL Server with Migration Wizard.
I want to keep database in Microsoft SQL Server in Japanese.

I was thinking to make the same database in English. With every changes in Japanese table, there will be changes in English version. And in the same time I will migrate data from English database to MySQL Server.
Is it a good way to migrate such data or are there better ways to deal with that?

Comment: sounds like migration wizard is the problem; not sure why you would want to change the column names just to move the data.  have you tried doing an sql dump and modifying types, etc for mysql and loading it?

Comment: We can't guess how you made the migration. MySQL lacks a *lot* of SQL Server's features. One of the issues is the quirky Unicode support - instead of an explicit Unicode type like `nvarchar`, you need to explicitly specify a [Unicode character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode.html) on `varchar` columns

Comment: According to the [MySql docs on object names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) Unicode characters *should* be permitted. I suspect if you create the tables yourself the names will work. The MySQL Workbench Wizard never expected this, so it fails.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fwiw to me sql server sounds a lot more quirky, with the nvarchar width counting byte-pairs, not characters.

Comment: @ysth not really `select len(N'πατάτες')` returns 7. Unless you talk about surrogate characters which *are* extra characters. There's no ambiguity or conversion errors when Unicode is actually Unicode and not up to interpretation. Which is why Java, JavaScript, Python 3, .NET strings are Unicode, not bytes+codepage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos interesting.  so an nvarchar(1) can store 1 character, even if in UTF-16 that character takes 4 bytes?  that's not what it sounded like from what I read

Comment: What you read was wrong. Although that confusion is common when you *don't* actually use Unicode, but treat it as something special. Which is a somewhat geographically-defined situation. Even some English words (naïve, Brontë) can't be represented with just the 7-bit ASCII character set. For the 7Bn people *not* using the Latin 1 character set, text *means* Unicode, since the 1990s

Comment: Same confusion is happening in the last few years in Python, with the migration to Unicode strings in Python 3. Lots of Python questions ask how to convert strings from/to Unicode not realizing their strings are already Unicode

Comment: nvarchar(1) can store 2 bytes of data, ymwv on what that means

Comment: @ysth sql dump seems good, but problem that I want to update DB in real time. Like insert information to mysql server and send it to mysql server. I tried to make a straight connection to sql server, but seems that in my php project there is a restriction to add sql server extension like "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql". That's why I tried another way